# Webpack with Express application generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I am totally new to Expressjs (Nodejs) and I am using "Express application generator" here is a [link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). I am building simple website and using (Embedded JavaScript templating / EJS) and I want to add webpack to my app.

Here is my project structure.

[image: picture]

Here is my app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var app = express();


    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   // set path for static assets
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


   // routes
   app.use('/', index);

   // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('404 page.');
   err.status = 404;
   next(err);
   });

   // error handler
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {status:err.status, message:err.message});
  });

  module.exports = app;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it, some example or anything that would help me?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

Webpack is for single page application.  There is only one index.html as the
hook, all the **front-end** contents will be generated by js files and bundled together by webpack then attached to the html hook.

If you use ejs or other template engine, you don't need webpack bundling your scripts, since you can split and load the scripts in your ejs files.

And your **app.js and other Express things** are backend things which run on your server, they don't need to be bundled or manipulated at all, you can do whatever you want, since those are on your server not users' browsers.

so just start to code your application.

Comment: @jomskris You are welcome, if you think this is helpful please consider to upvote or choose as right answer. : )

Comment: That’s not entirely true, though. Webpack is for bundling clientside assets, but it doesn’t mean you have to have a SPA to make use of it.  Even if you are running a traditional app, you might want to run a build process to convert Typescript to JS or even just to combine and minify to improve page load time.

Comment: @Paul, Agree, in that case, there are many other tools like gulp dedicated to  that.